# add space between two images in container in codenameone

Tags: codenameone

I am trying to add  6 images in container, but the gap between two images is large as shown in fig below. I tried this code.

```
class TestPallet extends Container {

    TestIcon firstIcon;
    TestIcon secondIcn;
    TestIcon thirdIcn;
    TestIcon fourIcn;


    Container panel;

    public TestPallet() {
        super();
        panel= new Container();
        panel.getStyle().setBgColor(0x323232);
        panel.getStyle().setBgTransparency(255);
        panel.setLayout(new BoxLayout(BoxLayout.X_AXIS));
        panel.getStyle().setBorder(Border.createLineBorder(2, 0xffffff));
        panel.getStyle().setPadding(10, 10,10,10);
        panel.getStyle().setMargin(50, 10, 10, 10);
        panel.setSelectedStyle(panel.getStyle());

        Container row1 = new Container();
        row1.setLayout(new BoxLayout(BoxLayout.X_AXIS));

        int margin = Display.getInstance().convertToPixels(1, true);


        firstIcon = new ShapeIcon(1, this);
        panel.addComponent(firstIcon);

        secondIcn = new ShapeIcon(2, this);
        panel.addComponent(secondIcn);


        thirdIcn = new ShapeIcon(3, this);
        panel.addComponent(thirdIcn);

        fourIcn = new ShapeIcon(4, this);
        panel.addComponent(fourIcn);

        addComponent(panel);

    }
}
class TestIcon extends Container{

    boolean selected=false;
    ShapePallet pallet;
    int t;

    public TestIcon(int s, ShapePallet sp) {
        super();
        pallet=sp;
        t=s;
        getStyle().setBgTransparency(0);
        getStyle().setBgColor(0xdcdcdc);
        this.setSelectedStyle(this.getStyle());
        setFocusable(true);

    }

    @Override
    public void paint(Graphics g) {

        int size = Display.getInstance().convertToPixels(2, false);

        Image im= null;

        if(t==1) {
            size *= 2;
            im = DisplayManager.getWmUiBuilder().getResources().getImage("image1.png").scaled(size, size);

        }

        else if(t== 2) {
            size *= 2;
            im = DisplayManager.getWmUiBuilder().getResources().getImage("image2.png").scaled(size, size );

        }

        else if(t== 3) {
            size *= 2;
            im = DisplayManager.getWmUiBuilder().getResources().getImage("image3.png").scaled(size, size);

        }

        else if(t== 4) {
            size *= 2;
            im = DisplayManager.getWmUiBuilder().getResources().getImage("image4.png").scaled(size, size);

        }

    g.drawImage(im,getX() + ((getWidth() - im.getWidth())) / 2, getY() + ((getHeight() - im.getHeight()) / 2));

    }

}
```

[image]

As you can see from image, the space between two images is too large, and this is from iPad, on Iphone I can see only two images. In this case also, one image is missing.
So, how to reduce the gap between two images? Any answers on this will be helpful. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest using styles.

You need to set the padding/margin units as well, ideally use millimeters and set the numbers to lower values. E.g. `setPaddingUnit`/`setMarginUnit` to either `Style.UNIT_TYPE_PIXELS` or `Style.UNIT_TYPE_DIPS`.

A better approach would be using gridlayout which will evenly space the components within it.